# How do I make my container increase itself when the children increase?

Tags: html, css

I have this div.container in which I have a heading and a form.
I have other pages with other forms too, but this container stays in just one height.
I want the container to increase or decrease its height depending on my form.
How do I make my container increase itself when the children increase?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

body {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 28px;
  position: static;
}

.container {
  width: 940px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 8% auto;
  background: #f3f6f7;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.container form {
  width: 280px;
}

form input {
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Example</h2>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Google Meet ID" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="LinkedIn Profile" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Google Meet ID" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="LinkedIn Profile" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Google Meet ID" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="LinkedIn Profile" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Google Meet ID" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="LinkedIn Profile" required />
    <div class="btn-box">
      <button type="button">Back</button>
      <button type="button">Next</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Also, how do I bring the form to the center?

Comment: could you show your div layout and the css as a [mcve]? Read [ask]

Comment: There you go,
Sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: What do you mean with increase? height, width? what is working so far as intended? What is your intended layout? -> Add a drawing

Comment: increase in height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `min-height` for the container (i added `max-width` and `width: 80%` to fit in the small stack snippet). Then you can use `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column;` and `margin: auto` for the form to align it in the center of the container. Finally you can also use `margin: auto` for the inputs and the button box for aligning them in the center of the form.

**Working example:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

body {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 28px;
  position: static;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
  max-width: 940px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin: 8% auto;
  background: #f3f6f7;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.container form {
  width: 280px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form input {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.btn-box {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Example</h2>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Google Meet ID" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="LinkedIn Profile" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Google Meet ID" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="LinkedIn Profile" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Google Meet ID" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="LinkedIn Profile" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Google Meet ID" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="LinkedIn Profile" required />
    <div class="btn-box">
      <button type="button">Back</button>
      <button type="button">Next</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This, unfortunately, did not work
I did make changes in my question to be precise.

Answer (score 2):

You can literally just remove `height: 500px;` from the `.container {}` style.

Block elements expand to fit their children by default. By restraining the container's height, you're forcing it to overflow.

You also don't need `position: static;` on your `h2` unless you've set a different position style on `h2`'s elsewhere. `static` is the default.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

body {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.container {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 8% auto;
  background: #f3f6f7;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.container form {
  width: 280px;
}

form input {
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Example</h2>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Google Meet ID" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="LinkedIn Profile" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Google Meet ID" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="LinkedIn Profile" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Google Meet ID" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="LinkedIn Profile" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Google Meet ID" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="LinkedIn Profile" required />
    <div class="btn-box">
      <button type="button">Back</button>
      <button type="button">Next</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @SuhaibAhmed, if you think this is the better answer you can change the accepted answer :)

Comment: This is definitely the better answer, @SuhaibAhmed. (And you should mark it as such). It should be important general knowledge that in HTML, parent containers expand _by default_.